# How to avoid block retains in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I have a queue of blocks which perform a webservice call. The problem is that the downloaded data is not freed after the block's end. I read a lot about retains but I can't make ARC dealloc the memory.

Here's the code:

1. Create the queue of blocks which download the data

   ```
   - (void)syncData
   {
       dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
       dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);

       dispatch_async(queue, ^{

           [Model syncAziende:^(id response, NSError *error) {
               dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
           }];
           dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

           [Model syncContatti:^(id response, NSError *error) {
               dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
           }];
           dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

           [Model syncDestinazioni:^(id response, NSError *error) {
               dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
           }];
           dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

           and so on...

       });
   }
   ```
2. On Model.m

   ```
   + (void)syncAziende:(RequestFinishBlock)completation
   {
       __weak typeof(self)selfObject = self;

       [selfObject syncData:^(id response, NSError *error) {
           completation(response,error);
       } wsEndPoint:kCDCEndPointGetAziende tableName:kCDCDBAziendeTableName];
   }

   + (void)syncContatti:(RequestFinishBlock)completation
   {
       __weak typeof(self)selfObject = self;

       [selfObject syncData:^(id response, NSError *error) {
           completation(response,error);
       } wsEndPoint:kCDCEndPointGetContatti tableName:kCDCDBContattiTableName];
   }

   // and so on...
   ```
3. Where `syncData` is:

   ```
   + (void)syncData:(RequestFinishBlock)completation wsEndPoint:(NSString*) url tableName:(NSString *)table
   {
       __weak typeof(self)selfObject = self;

       [selfObject getDataFromWS:^(id WSresponse, NSError* WSError)
        {
            completation(nil,nil);
        }WSUrl:url];
   }
   ```
4. Where `getDataFromWS` is:

   ```
   + (void)getDataFromWS:(RequestFinishBlock)completation WSUrl:(NSString *)svcUrl
   {
       __weak typeof(self)selfObject = self;
       [selfObject getJsonDataFromURL:^(id response, NSError *error)
        {
            completation(response,error);
        }url:svcUrl];
   }
   ```
5. Where `getJsonDataFromURL` is:

   ```
   +(void)getJsonDataFromURL:(RequestFinishBlock)completation url:(NSString*)url
   {
       __weak typeof(self)selfObject = self;

       __weak AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [selfObject getAuthorizedRequestionOperationManager];

       [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
       [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
       [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

       [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, __weak id responseObject) {
           completation([responseObject objectForKey:@"d"],nil);
       } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
           completation(nil,error);
       }];
   }
   ```

Comment: Please paste the code in your question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code

Comment: Try to use the __block for the downloaded data.

Comment: @KuoMingLin where exactly?

Comment: @KuoMingLin No, `__block` will not solve anything.

Comment: @Rob could the problem be in AFNetworking ?

Comment: Which object, precisely, is allegedly not getting released? The object that has `syncData` as an instance method? I don't see what would retain that. The rest of your code is all class methods (and, BTW, the `__weak` references therefore don't quite makes sense). But regardless of whether `syncData` object's retained or not, your block will continue to execute even after that object has been released. There are far easier ways to accomplish what you're trying to do. But, no, the problem is not AFNetworking.

Comment: @Rob what is not getting released is the download data wich is id responseObject wich afnetoworking returns.

Comment: @user3463206 I'm surprised by that, as it looks like `[+Model syncData:...]` discards the returned data, but I'd retire that dispatch to `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` with all of the semaphore code, because that could easily be the culprit.

Comment: Rather than asking how to avoid objects being retained in a block, you should describe what you are trying to accomplish. Your current design has a *number* of code smells. It's not worth sticking with it and trying to find the reason for a tiny "claw mark", and there's no fix: you need an appropriate design first, which is capable to solve asynchronous problems. Your's is not.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper What I have to do is synchronize iPad database with one of web service. Every web service call returns row table wich has to be written to sqlite database. I have to do this serially because user need to know what iPad is synching and to not get database locked after getting data. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: As far as I can tell all the uses of `__weak` in your code, all of which are incorrect (the use of it as the type of a block argument is particular strange - think out it!), have been added by you in an attempt to solve your problem (see this [pastie](http://pastie.org/pastes/8975651)). If this is the case I suggest you replace the code by your original pre-fix attempt and then describe your problem in relation to that code.

Comment: @user3463206 Unrelated to your problem at hand, when using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, rather than setting header values, you should just do `manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]`. Just use the right serializer, rather than messing around with header settings.

Comment: @user3463206 Related to your question about doing serial requests so that you can update your database serially, it seems like you're conflating two issues. I do concurrent network requests, but then have dedicated serial queue for database updates. Don't slow down your network requests because you want to write data to your database serially. Do network requests concurrently, but do the database updates serially (and the database updates will still be faster). If you do your network requests serially, you're unnecessarily slowing down the download process.

Answer (score 0):

These `__weak` references don't really make sense within the context of a class method. It only makes sense to use the `weak`-`self` pattern when dealing with instance methods.

So, this begs the question as to which object you're concerned about not getting released. I don't see anything here that would cause the object that has `syncData` as an instance method to be retained.

Having said that, this routine with the series of network requests that you have made synchronous through the use of the semaphores would (a) retain any autorelease objects that were instantiated throughout the process (notably, the operations themselves); (b) not allow you to cancel the process once it starts; and (c) run the requests serially (for which you'll pay a serious performance penalty and should be avoided unless you absolutely have to).

I'd suggest a simplification of the code. I'd eliminate the dispatch code with the semaphores. I'd also get rid of all of those `weak` references to `self` in class methods.

You should simply issue your `GET` requests. If you really need them to run serially (as implied by your use of the semaphore), then just set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to `1` for the `operationQueue` of the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` instance. But don't make them run serially unless you absolutely have to, because you pay a significant performance penalty by doing that. But avail yourself of the `NSOperationQueue` that AFNetworking provides, rather than also doing your own GCD code (and worse, using semaphores within that GCD code).

But this way, if you want to cancel the requests, you can just call `cancelAllOperations` for the `operationQueue` of the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`. You can also control the degree of concurrency with `maxConcurrentOperationCount`.

Comment: Thanks for useful informations but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @user3463206 Maybe I'm being unclear: I think that you could get objects being retained unnecessarily long when you dispatch a long series of requests synchronously using semaphores. That's why I'm suggesting you get rid of that construct.

Comment: pastie.org/8979057 Why does ARC dealloc (why not ALL downloaded objects???) at the end of the queue?

Comment: @user3463206 I don't understand the question. I create a queue for download operations and then added 100+ operations to that queue (http://pastie.org/8979236) and as the individual operations finished, they were deallocated. Note, if you're not going to use `AFHTTPResponseManager` (which enqueues GET, POST, etc., requests on its own dedicated operation queue) then create a dedicated queue for your requests like I did here. If you use `AFHTTPResponseManager`, that's not necessary, because `GET`, `POST`, etc., methods will enqueue them in an `NSOperationQueue` that AFNetworking creates itself.

Answer (score 0):

Given your description and based on the comments, a naive - but still insufficient - 
solution may look as follows:

// A generic completion handler:
    typedef void (^completion_t)(id result, NSError* error);

```
- (void) fetchJSONFromURL:(NSURL*)url completion:(completion_t)completion;

- (void) syncAziendeWithInput:(id)input completion:(completion_t)completion;

- (void) syncContattiWithInput:(id)input completion:(completion_t)completion;

- (void) syncDestinazioniWithInput:(id)input completion:(completion_t)completion;



- (void) syncData 
{
    dispatch_queue_t sync_queue = dispatch_queue_create("sync_queue", 0); // serial queue

    NSURL* url = ...;
    [self fetchJSONFromURL:url completion:^(id result, NSError*error){
        dispatch_async(sync_queue, ^{
            [self syncAziendeWithInput:result completion:^(id result, NSError* error){
                ...
            }];
        });
    }];

    url = ...;
    [self fetchJSONFromURL:url completion:^(id result, NSError*error){
        dispatch_async(sync_queue, ^{
            [self syncContattiWithInput:result completion:^(id result, NSError* error){
                ...
            }];
        });
    }];

    url = ...;
    [self fetchJSONFromURL:url completion:^(id result, NSError*error){
        dispatch_async(sync_queue, ^{
            [self syncDestinazioniWithInput:result completion:^(id result, NSError* error){
                ...
            }];
        });
    }];


    ...
}
```

**Caveats:**

Oversimplification. A practical solution becomes far more elaborated:

- No error handling yet.
- No way to cancel the asynchronous tasks.
- `syncData` is asynchronous, but has no completion handler. That is, we don't know when it's complete. We could utilize `dispatch_group` in order to implement an approach to signal the completion of a number of asynchronous methods.

With the help of a third party library we could implement a solution which does all that above, and looks basically even simpler.